# paypal ec product discount not applied

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I've searched around and can't see any issues or bugs so thought I would ask the question first regarding Paypal EC when a product discount is applied.

I have recently installed/setup [Paypal EC](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) version 7.x-2.3 on a production site and have come across an issue when purchasing a product that has a product discount applied.

The discounted value shows when logging into Paypal, after continuing back to the site and paying for the order, the original product value is taken with no sign of the discount on the order.

Has anyone else seen or experienced this?